# Angular 2 Universal - Server-side Rendering

Tags: angular

I was reading about Angular 2 Server side rendering with node.

But I cannot find an example or explain how should I do that.
I need to render some pages with angular from server, any advice?

Comment: My understanding from one of the more recent blog posts was that Angular 2.x server-side rendering was one of the last modules to be coded and is still fairly in-development.

Comment: You can check the repo of the project https://github.com/angular/universal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the example the creators of angular-universal used in their talk, its a working repo -> https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/tree/angular-connect

And this is the talk - [Full Stack Angular 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtoHFDfi8FM)

Answer (score 25):

Well, look at this starter kit
https://github.com/alexpods/angular2-universal-starter. It has **server side rendering**, **web workers support** (entire angular2 application is running in a web worker) , **lazy loading** (using webpack's code splitting) and many other things. I hope it will help you.

**Disclosure**: I'm its author.

Comment: does your code generates static html of my html page if it has few child components inside parent component ? because I was trying to do this using universal starter kit but didnt work

Comment: @BhushanGadekar Yes, of course. My starter generates static html with any number of child components.

Comment: where is static html generated & saved?

Comment: Nice I was looking for something like that !

Comment: @alexpods Can you tell me if jade/pug templating and stylus can be supported in that code? I tried to add those by using `require('main.styl')` (and proper loader in webpack) instead of inline CSS, but I get errors.

Comment: any plans to upgrade the starter app to ng4? 
official documentation sucks!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look here: https://universal.angular.io/

Looks like 'some' of the official documentation/site is now up. API docs are in the code but for quick reference see these links:

https://universal.angular.io/api/universal/index.html#typedoc-main-index
https://universal.angular.io/api/preboot/globals.html

Nice third party overview and setup doc: https://mickaelkerjeanblog.wordpress.com/2016/05/02/angular-universal/

Answer (score 4):

There's another [example repo](https://github.com/ng-seed/universal) at https://github.com/ng-seed/universal showcasing both **Universal** and **lean Angular** on a single project.

This application uses `platform-server` delivered with **Angular 4.0.0**, and it could be a good starter/seed project until **Angular** provides some documentation about the use of `platform-server`.

Furthermore, it covers most of the features of [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/) by [AngularClass](https://github.com/AngularClass) such as async/**lazy** routes, **SCSS** compilation (*both inline and external*), dev/prod modes, **AoT** compilation via `@ngtools/webpack`, tests, TsLint/Codelyzer, @types and maybe more.

**Disclosure:** I'm the author too :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this searching in July 2018 and thought it has probably changed since then.  Now we're on Angular 6 and there's a good tutorial [here](https://hackernoon.com/deploying-angular-universal-v6-with-firebase-c86381ddd445) for using it with firebase.

The angular docs are here: https://angular.io/guide/universal.

You have an `app.server.module` that imports `ServerModule` from `@angular/platform-server` and your regular app module:

```
imports: [
  ServerModule,
  AppModule
],
```

And in your normal `AppModule` you call `withServerTransition` when you import the `BrowserModule`.

```
BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: APP_ID })
```

You have a separate main for server side rendering that just exports your server module:

```
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
```

The relevant part that runs the express server looks like this:

```
const { renderModuleFactory } = require('@angular/platform-server');
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory } = require('./dist/server/main');

const index = require('fs')
  .readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/browser/index.html'), 'utf8')
  .toString();

let app = express();

app.get('**', function(req, res) {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    url: req.path,
    document: index
  }).then(html => res.status(200).send(html));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

angular server side rendering step by step run below comment

Step 1: ->`ng add @ng-toolkit/universal`

step 2:->`npm install`

step 3:->`npm run build:prod`

step 4:->`ng build --prod`

step 5:->`npm run server`

step 6:-> run cmd and write the command ->`curl http://localhost:4000`

my server side angular application https://exampreparation.study

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 kinds of Server side Rendering

### Dynamic SSR (server-side rendering) & Static Pre-rendering

**Dynamic SSR** is the concept that there will be a live Node server spun up that whenever a Route is hit, it will dynamically generate and serialize the application — returning that String to the browser.
Remember, you cannot put this is in AWS S3 or nginx or apache httpd, you need a node server running somewhere.

**Static Pre-rendering** is when we want to pre-render a list of routes, and create static files, (ie: index.html, about-us.html, etc) and then use a server of our choosing to serve up those files later on. You can deploy this using AWS S3 or nginx or apache httpd just like a normal angular app.

### So how do we know which one to choose and when?

Pre-rendering will typically give you better performance since we’re not waiting for a server to hit all the necessary APIs within your application, and nothing has to be “serialized”, it already has all the serialized HTML of your application outputted for each one of the Routes files.
Here’s a good list of questions that we consider with clients before considering which route we need to take.

### When to use Static Pre-Rendering:

- Your application itself is rather Static.
  (or at least the Routes you’re trying to pre-render)
  For example: homepage | about us | contact us
- Very dynamic portions of your site (and ones that are behind a Login/Auth barrier) can be pointed to the normal Client-side rendered (CSR) version of your application, and Angular can bootstrap itself normally.
- Your application doesn’t update very often.
  Whenever some changes are needed on the static routes, you can simply run the build script again and republish the /dist folder containing all of your pre-rendered files.

### When to use Dynamic SSR:

- Your application (and the routes you need to SSR) are very dynamic
- You have a list of “trending products” | “live data” | etc, that you need populated correctly for every server-side render.
- Your applications structure is rendered based on JSON files or a CMS where anything could change at any given moment.

**Typically most applications will need static pre-rendering** (since any routes behind an authentication-wall don’t gain much/any benefit from utilizing SSR, since one of the main purposes is the SEO gains, and improved perceived performance.
Remember, you can always have certain aspects of your application not render during SSR, and have those dynamic portions populated during CSR!

Reference
https://medium.com/@MarkPieszak/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-deep-dive-dc442a6be7b7

### How to do either (As of Dec 2019)

**For Dynamic SSR** Just follow along https://angular.io/guide/universal

For **Static Pre-rendering**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53725674/6785908

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23024