# Add static pre-rendering to ng add @nguniversal/express-engine

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I added server side rendering to my Angular project by following the Angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/universal#universal-tutorial).

I found out that the commands to run the **static pre-rendering** `npm run build:prerender` and `npm run serve:prerender` were not here after using the CLI command:

`ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [angular.projet]`

I am wondering if the static pre-rendering is still supported in Universal? The code generated is all about dynamic SSR.

That's weird because I found these commands on the [universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter).

Anyone have information about that? Also how can I add the static pre-rendering in my angular project?

To reproduce, run in the terminal :

- `ng new foo` to start a new project
- `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject foo` to add universal

Thanks for help.

Comment: You could add those scripts to your *package.json* by copying them from [here](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/package.json). Hard to tell if installing the `@nguniversal/express-engine` was meant to add them for you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a way to add the static pre-rendering manually.

For those interested, all the steps to manually add the static pre-rendering to the `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`:

1. `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [your project name]` to initialize the server-side app module, app.server.module.ts
2. Create the files `prerender.ts` and `static.paths.ts` at the root level of your project next to `server.ts`
3. Copy the content of https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/prerender.ts in your `prerender.ts` file
4. Create your routes in your `static.paths.ts` following the example https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/static.paths.ts
5. Add the prerender entry in your `webpack.server.config.js`:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     mode: 'none',
     entry: {
       server: './server.ts',
       prerender: './prerender.ts'
     },
   ```
6. Add the prerender scripts in your `package.json`:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       ...
       "build:prerender": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server && npm run generate:prerender",
       "generate:prerender": "cd dist && node prerender",
       "serve:prerender": "cd dist/browser && http-server"
     }
   ```
7. Edit the line 17 of your `prerender.ts` by

   ```
   const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');
   ```
8. Install the package **http-server** to serve the prerender build:

   ```
   npm install http-server --save-dev
   ```
9. You are now ready to go!

   ```
   npm run build:prerender && npm run serve:prerender


   Starting up http-server, serving ./
   Available on:
     http://127.0.0.1:8080
     http://192.168.0.10:8080
   Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
   ```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great @Johan! Can you tell me from where did you know how to do this?

Comment: @GauravRamanan from [https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23024](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23024) where I summarized all the steps.

Comment: @JohanRin .. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '<Project Folder>/dist/browser/lazy/nested' This is the error that I am getting now

Comment: ng --version

Angular CLI: 8.3.20
Node: 12.4.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.20
@angular-devkit/core         8.3.20
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.20
@schematics/angular          8.3.20
@schematics/update           0.803.20
rxjs                         6.4.0

Comment: Does anyone actually have a minimum working repo of this? Seems the node express version of the SSR demo looks to be depreciated on Github

Comment: The problem on my side is that when i first try to run the ```ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [your project name]``` It doesn`t add anything, it throws an error saying ```Universal requires a project type of application```

Answer (score 0):

[Edit]
Downgrading to **version 0.9.0** actually seems to be the best option.

Something to tack onto the accepted answer (can't comment yet) you might run into a **http-server** error if you **are using version .0.11.0**. There is a bug with ecstatic on version 0.11.0. If you are having the problem read the thread [here](https://github.com/http-party/http-server/issues/525) and check out some of the solutions. Either downgrade your version of ecstatic if you have this issue and don't want to upgrade http-server, or explicitly navigate to index.html to get your page to render.

I was very excited to get SSR up and running, but ran into this problem and it really ate up some time. I hope this helps.