# Debug compilation errors errors using Angular Universal in Angular 8 Application

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering

**A Brief Backstory**

I have been implementing several upgrades to an Angular 8 application such as server-side rendering, and Google Analytics. As most developers do, I would code then test then move on to the next task. Typically I use `ng serve` to run the application as I am developing.

With Server-side rendering, to test speed, lazy-loaded images, etc, you need to use a node express server running on a generated JS file. After building, etc, I use `Node prerender` (my js file is prerender.js) to see what the application will look like prerendering on the server.

When I run this command, I should not get any errors, and I know my prender file will start a local server on port 4000.

**The Problem**

I get errors when running a node express server that I do not get when running with `ng serve` I recently got an error that said:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at new ApplicationRef (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:45910:37)
    at _createClass (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:37184:20)
    at _createProviderInstance (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:37138:26)
    at initNgModule (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:37044:32)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:38176:9)
    at Object.createNgModuleRef (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:38159:12)
    at NgModuleFactory_.create (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:50821:25)
    at C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\prerender.js:29175:43
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\prerender.js:481:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\prerender.js:28683:33) TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at new ApplicationRef (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:45910:37)
    at _createClass (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:37184:20)
    at _createProviderInstance (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:37138:26)
    at initNgModule (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:37044:32)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:38176:9)
    at Object.createNgModuleRef (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:38159:12)
    at NgModuleFactory_.create (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\server\main.js:50821:25)
    at C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\prerender.js:29175:43
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\prerender.js:481:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (C:\4towerdevelopment\dist-stage\prerender.js:28683:33)
```

The closest this gets me to figuring what actually is causing the problem is letting me know that a provider somewhere is causing this error. Looks like something should be an observable rather than a subscription. Beyond that, I guess I just start looking through my providers. My question is:

1. How can I force Angular to possibly throw this error when developing using `ng serve`?
2. If I can't, is there a better way to debug this current error besides combing through each provider? Or at least a way to tell what service is causing the issue?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:** Basic repo with problem [here](https://github.com/WLK4Tower/prerender). I made a new angular project, made sure dependencies were up to date, installed ngUniversal per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677419/add-static-pre-rendering-to-ng-add-nguniversal-express-engine/59143633#59143633), and received this same Unhandled promise message when running `node prerender`

Verbatim I went to to the Angular cli website, made a new project (default Angular version installed was 8.3), installed Angular Universal, and tried to build. Same error message as above.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue? I'm running into the same exact error.

Comment: The closest I got was digging into their repo a bit. Supposedly the node example in there isn't up to date. Although it looks like it should still work. I'm going to take another swing at this in a few weeks and will post back more findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it was `ApplicationRef` that triggered the error, and that class is provided internally by the Angular core.

It could be failing in the constructor of the class, and there are a few calls to `subscribe` on Zone observables. I don't think you're going to find anything in your source code that directly relates to this error. It looks like a build configuration problem.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bb52fb798c8578c461d21aee2b7623232184a5d3/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L562

I do not know what could possibly produce this problem, but I would start a new project with SSR and compare the differences to your current project.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll start by just trying to get SSR to work on a very basic app, and see what happens, then comment back.

Comment: I have made a minimum repo that is producing the same error message. See question above.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I dropped the angular 6 approach using pre-render, and went with the latest universal package. There seems to be no problem building using `npm run build:ssr` and serving dist/server.js in an express server. I am not sure what the problem was with the pre-render approach, but it seems to be outdated anyways. @Reactgular thanks for the feedback.